# How to convert string of list of list to list?

Tags: python, list

I have this file, it is the result of the MapReduce job so it has `key-value` format:

```
'null\t[0, [[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]]]\n'
'null\t[1, [[0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]]]\n'
```

I want to remove all the character except the second element of this value list:

```
[[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
[[0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

And finally, add each to a single list:

```
[[[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]], [[0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]]]
```

This is my attempt so far:

```py
with open(FILENAME) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    # Just match all the chars upto "[[" then replace the matched chars with "["
    clean_line = re.sub(r'^.*?\[\[', '[', line)
    # And remove "\n" and the last 2 "]]" of the string
    clean_line = re.sub('[\n]', '', clean_line)[:-2]
    corpus.append(clean_line)
```

Output:

```
['[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]', '[0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]']
```

You can see it is still `str` type, how can I make it to `list` type?

Comment: would `json.loads('null\t[0, [[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]]]\n'.replace('null\t', '{"a":').replace("\n", "}"))["a"]` work for you?

Comment: you could don't remove the inner brackets and use  `json.loads`

Comment: @Sayse It will return `[0, [[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]]]` and I just need to add `json.loads('null\t[0, [[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]]]\n'.replace('null\t', '{"a":').replace("\n", "}"))["a"][1]` to get what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat it as a line of json and just replace parts of your lines with json documents as needed

```
import json
corpus = [json.loads(line.replace('null\t', '{"a":').replace("\n", "}"))["a"][1] for line in content]
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end, you can convert representations of list to List object by using `ast` like this:

```
import ast
sample = ['[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]', '[0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]']
result = []
for item in sample:
    result.append(list(ast.literal_eval(item)))
```

And this is the `result` containing the desired elements:

```
[[[0, 21], [1, 4], [2, 5]], [[0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]]]
```